# What development tool do you recommend for animation/games in lieu of Flash?

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript

I had written an interactive quiz application in Flash 8 years ago. It was pretty darned robust in ActionScript 2.0, and virtually impossible to port to ActionScript 3.0 without a complete rewrite, and abandonment of the timeline as an animation tool.

Have any of you moved on to something else? I would like the ability to run movie clips with embedded alpha layers, handle key presses and mouse clicks, and do simple moves and zooms of blocks of text.

Comment: That features set is a pretty accurate description of flash. So what does flash have that is a deal breaker?

Comment: Well, Flash works if I stay with ActionScript 2.0. However, 3.0 inexorably pushes one to do all the heavy lifting in code rather than the graphic interface that made Flash so useful in the first place. Imaging calculating and entering coordinates for all your movement rather than just putting them on the stage. Further, making all scripts go on one timeline rather than having robust objects that talk to each other is frustrating.

Comment: Frankin - I fear you are misinformed about AS3. There is still the Flash IDE, and still the timeline, and still movieclips. The only part that changes is the code. I'd recommend downloading the 30 demo of adobe flash 5.5 and check it out. And you can still export as AS2 if you want. Though who would want to...

Comment: Well, Plastic Sturgeon, I shall not close the door on my mind - but my experience so far with AS3 is this: take a fully functioning program, attempt to change it to AS3. Placing an instance of a functioning movie clip (with internal scripting) on the timeline works not at all, and I get advised in this forum that I would have to instantiate it completely from code. I follow tutorial scripts for listening for key presses and get very spotty results, and walking the forums tells me that I am not alone.  I shall take a breather, look at the example you mentioned, and think on it some more. :)

Comment: Well you're right on some counts. You can't "attach" code to symbols anymore in AS3. And as2 code won't run in an AS3 movie. But in your question you're looking for a new toolkit, which implies a full rebuild anyway. So I would just suggest considering flash as the rebuild tool, since it has the features you want, and I don't know of any other tool that has stage, movieclips etc and the IDE tool for animation. I hope you find a good solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you're looking for a new toolkit, which implies a full rebuild. So I would just suggest considering flash as the rebuild tool, since it has the features you want, and I don't know of any other tool that has stage, movieclips etc and the IDE tool for animation. I hope you find a good solve.

You might also like some tools like Stencyl that are similar in some ways to flash (it publishes to flash) but has a visual programming interface.
http://www.stencyl.com/

For windows and Xbox there is XNA studio
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23714

and of course and interactive quiz is possible to be written in any programming language, including javascript or python among countless others.